# how to go to previous node in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Are there anyways to go back to previous node in firebase. with php you can do `..` and it will bring you to the previous director. thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the ***parent key*** that you jumped to come to that particular node, try this:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("your_Root/your_Child1/your_Child2").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snapshot) in

       let parentKey = Snapshot.ref.parent!.key

        print(parentKey)   // Will print out "your_Child2"

    })
```

Comment: Accept and upvote this as answer if it solved your issue :) Happy Coding